# Exception caught by widgets library: The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a flutter app that stores data via SharedPreferences from the textfield. Then the data will be displayed dynamically in the SecondScreen. While making this app, I stumbled upon this error "NoSuchMethodError". I'm trying to figure it out but I don't know where's the exact location of the error and how to solve this all by myself. Can you please help me to solve this? Here it says:

```
The relevant error-causing widget was
SecondScreen
package:midterm_exam/main.dart:111
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      DynamicList.build
package:midterm_exam/main.dart:163
#2      StatefulElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4684
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4567
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4739
```

Here's my code for the SecondScreen:

```
class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new DynamicList();
}

class DynamicList extends State<SecondScreen> {
  List<String> dataLists = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getStudentData();
  }

  getStudentData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var studentData = prefs.getStringList("data");
    setState(() {
      dataLists = studentData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: dataLists.length, itemBuilder: buildList),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            width: 2,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(dataLists[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could get `null` as your `dataLists` is if your reading from preferences returned `null`.

That makes me think you are using an old version of Dart/Flutter, because it should not even *compile* with a newer version.

But if you want to stay with the old version, your could do this:

```
setState(() {
  dataLists = studentData ?? [];
});
```

Which means if `studentData` happens to be `null`, use an empty list instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
 Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: dataLists.length, 
  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
          return  Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            width: 2,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
      child: ListTile(
        title: Text(dataLists[index]),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and comment out `Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {..etc`

Also, looks like your shared prefs is returning a null value.

```
 getStudentData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List studentData =[];
    studentData = prefs.getStringList("data");
    setState(() {
      dataLists = studentData ?? [];//this will check if it's null before assinging it.
    });
  }
```

I would double check this again `prefs.getStringList("data")`, seems like it's returning a null value.

Comment: What would that change? It seems all you took out is the function. But that would not have caused the error, would it?